# Text isn't wrapping underneath of itself

Tags: html, css

I have a collection of divs as rows that can be variable width as they are inside a resizable container. The div contains 4 groups of elements that I want to be displayed side by side. Of these 4 groups, 2 of the groups need to be variable width while the other 2 are fixed. I have it mostly working except the last group isn't wrapping the way I want it to. I can't put a margin-left on it because of the variable width sibling. I also tried setting each item as `inline-block` but that forced the last group to have a strange calculated width that was larger than the available space and always forced it below the other 3 groups.

**[Here's a live example/fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vEek/)** and the source is as follows:

HMTL:

```
<div class="row level-2 note subtype-new subtype-fancy">
    <div class="leading col"><a class="note-icon icon" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></div>
    <div class="padded">
        <div class="status-icon-wrapper col">
          <span class="new-icon icon"></span>
          <span class="modified-icon icon" title="Revised Code"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="codes-wrapper col">
          <span class="codes"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="code ">XYZ</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-wrapper col">
          <span class="fancy-icon icon"></span>
          <span class="plain-icon icon"></span>
          <span class="disabled-icon icon"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="description">Description text that should wrap underneath of itself should go here. Description text that should wrap underneath of itself should go here. Description text that should wrap underneath of itself should go here. Description text that should wrap underneath of itself should go here. Description text that should wrap underneath of itself should go here. Description text that should wrap underneath of itself should go here. Description text that should wrap underneath of itself should go here. Description text that should wrap underneath of itself should go here.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {margin: 3px 0 3px 2px; overflow: hidden; outline: 1px solid #000}
.col {float: left}
.icon {display: inline-block; height: 16px; width: 16px; line-height: 16px; outline: 1px dotted #0CC; background-color:}
.level-1 .padded {padding-left: 30px}
.level-2 .padded {padding-left: 60px}

.codes-wrapper,
.icon-wrapper {padding-right: 3px}

.status-icon-wrapper,
.icon-wrapper {width: 17px}

.row .icon {display:none}
.note-icon {background-color: #F0F}

.fancy-icon {background-color: #CC0}
.plain-icon {background-color: #C00}
.new-icon {background-color: #0CC}

.note .note-icon,
.subtype-new .new-icon,
.subtype-modified .modified-icon,
.subtype-fancy .fancy-icon,
.subtype-plain .plain-icon,
.subtype-disabled .disabled-icon
{display: inline-block}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.description {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/8vEek/1/)

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow

hidden : This value indicates that the content **is clipped** ...

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties  and  http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/overflow

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you should add:

```
.description{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

to your CSS